# Spring @PreAuthorize is not working on PATCH request

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-data-jpa, jpql

In the following code I want to update the rider , Query works fine but I also want to check the authority of logged-In user but following code is not working

In the First query `completeOrder` `@PreAuthorized` annotation works but inthe second query it does not work

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

     @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('rights')")
     @Query("Select o from Order o where o.orderStatus='DELIVERED'")
     List<Order> completedOrder(); 

     @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('rights')")
     @Modifying
     @Query("Update Order o set o.rider=:riderId where o.id= :orderId")
     List<Order> changeRider();
}
```

Comment: I believe this is a known bug. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-877

Comment: issue is unresolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem is solved now, mistake is not in my code , actually I am sending different API call and check this API :| My bad